# MySQl Error #1064 Stored Procedure IF ELSE with multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am using MySQL via phyMyAdmin on GoDaddy.  I can execute this statement and one integer value is returned without any problems:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = 2) LIMIT 0,1;
```

However, when I attempt to create the following stored procedure I get the following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 25

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spGetPreferredRunNumbers`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetPreferredRunNumbers`(IN prefTimeRange INT(4), INOUT run1 INT(4), INOUT run2 INT(4), INOUT run3 INT(4), INOUT run4 INT(4), INOUT run5 INT(4))
BEGIN
IF (prefTimeRange = 2) THEN BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 0,1  INTO run1;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 1,1  INTO run2;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 2,1  INTO run3;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 3,1  INTO run4;
SET run5 = -1;
END;
ELSE IF (prefTimeRange = 3) THEN BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 0,1  INTO run1;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 1,1  INTO run2;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 2,1  INTO run3;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 3,1  INTO run4;
SET run5 = -1;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 0,1  INTO run1;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 1,1  INTO run2;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 2,1  INTO run3;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 3,1  INTO run4;
SELECT DISTINCT `runNumber` FROM RideSlot WHERE (timeRange = prefTimeRange) LIMIT 4,1  INTO run5;
END;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Yes, I have tested the other select statements with different limits individually and they work fine too, except when you use 2 or 3 for prefTimeRange when selecting LIMIT 4,1.  The prefTimeRange's 2 & 3 only return four results so I am assigning -1 to run5 if the prefTimeRange is 2 or 3.

I get the same exact error whether or not I do this: `prefTimeRange = 3`  or this:  `prefTimeRange = "3"`

Yes, I am remembering to tell phpMyAdmin that the proper delimiter is $$.

What am I missing????

Comment: You need to change the delimiter before starting creating procedure...  `delimiter $$` check whether you have done this ??

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Meherzad, but as I stated near the bottom of the post, I am remembering to do that.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: As it turns out the space between the ELSE and the IF needed to be removed!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad mysql issue and no where properly documented.
MYSQL stored procedure - if you leave a extra line or space before ELSE then the else part executes no mater what.

```
IF <your condition> then
<do this code>
                   <-- extra empty line
ELSE
<this always executes no matter what is in IF statement>
```

in above example - if you leave a empty line above ELSE , the else part always executes. DO NOT LEAVE EXTRA LINE above else part of if-else.